# When to use Mono.never()?

Tags: java, spring, reactive-programming, project-reactor, spring-webflux

I have read through the Javadocs for the `reactor.core.publisher.Mono` class From project reactor However I still don't understand what's the point of having the `Mono.never()` method.

What are some example use cases where one would use `Mono.never()`?

Answer (score 8):

It is very often used in tests (typically to assert timeout behavior), but can also have production usage: some operators take a control `Publisher` as parameter in various situations where they need an asynchronous external signal to tell them to trigger some behavior. If in some cases you don't want said behavior to trigger, user `never()`.

For instance, `windowWhen` takes such parameter both for opening and closing windows (the later generated by a `Function`). Conditionally returning a `Mono.never()` you could have a window that never closes.